# torch.onnx.export reports "Module onnx is not installed!"

Tags: pytorch, onnx

while I am executing torch.onnx.export() call it fails as below.

`============= Diagnostic Run torch.onnx.export version 2.0.1+cu117 =============
verbose: False, log level: Level.ERROR
======================= 0 NONE 0 NOTE 0 WARNING 0 ERROR ========================

Module onnx is not installed!`

I already tried "pip uninstall torch torchvision onnx"  and then "pip install torch torchvision onnx". But this doesn't help me.

I want to resolve reported error.